# Add "collection" of attributes directly to top level of a class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am trying to capture (S3) logs in a structured way.  I am capturing the access-related elements with this type of tuple:

```py
class _Access(NamedTuple):
    time: datetime
    ip: str
    actor: str
    request_id: str
    action: str
    key: str
    request_uri: str
    status: int
    error_code: str
```

I then have a class that uses this named tuple as follows (edited just down to relevant code):

```py
class Logs:
    def __init__(self, log: str):
        raw_logs = match(S3_LOG_REGEX, log)
        if raw_logs is None:
            raise FormatError(log)
        logs = raw_logs.groups()
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(logs[2], "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")
        http_status = int(logs[9])
        access = _Access(
            timestamp,
            logs[3],
            logs[4],
            logs[5],
            logs[6],
            logs[7],
            logs[8],
            http_status,
            logs[10],
        )
        self.access = access
```

The problem is that it is too verbose when I now want to use it:

```py
>>> log_struct = Logs(raw_log)
>>> log_struct.access.action # I don't want to have to add `access`
```

As I mention above, I'd rather be able to do something like this:

```py
>>> log_struct = Logs(raw_log)
>>> log_struct.action
```

But I still want to have this clean named tuple called `_Access`.  How can I make everything from `access` available at the top level?

Specifically, I have this line:

```py
        self.access = access
```

which is giving me that extra "layer" that I don't want.  I'd like to be able to "unpack" it somehow, similar to how we can unpack arguments by passing the star in `*args`.  But I'm not sure how I can unpack the tuple in this case.

Comment: Do you care about type safety? i.e. autocompletes or static analysis tooling like mypy?

Comment: Also, its unclear why the `Logs` class needs to exist over a factory function that returns an instance of `_Access` directly. e.g. `log_struct = parse_log_line(raw_log)` with `def parse_log_line(log: str) -> _Access`

Comment: Is there a good reason to have separate classes for `Log` and `_Access`? It doesn't look like `Log` is holding any other state except the `access` attribute, so I would say to remove one of those classes.

Comment: You should consider to create a custom class with a custom __iter__ method. This method defines what the * operator unpacks

Comment: @wim , there are other things that Log is doing.  I simplified the class to get to the main purpose.  But the "wrapper" class has several other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really need for your use case is an alternative constructor for your `NamedTuple` subclass to parse a string of a log entry into respective fields, which can be done by creating a class method that calls the `__new__` method with arguments parsed from the input string.

Using just the fields of `ip` and `action` as a simplified example:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Logs(NamedTuple):
    ip: str
    action: str

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, log: str) -> 'Logs':
        return cls.__new__(cls, *log.split())

log_struct  = Logs.parse('192.168.1.1 GET')
print(log_struct)
print(log_struct.ip)
print(log_struct.action)
```

This outputs:

```
Logs(ip='192.168.1.1', action='GET')
192.168.1.1
GET
```

Comment: This *might* do what I want, but I'm not sure:  I need for `Logs` to do more than just act as a `NamedTuple`.  It has several other methods that I didn't capture.  Can I use `class Logs(NamedTuple)` and still add more methods to Logs?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Yes you are free to add more methods, although you are not allowed to add more instance attributes. If you do need to add more instance attributes, you will need to fall back to one of the solutions in flakes' answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing) and recommend that solution. This is assuming that there are not extra attributes required to be apply to the named tuple (say storing the raw log value).

If you really need the object to remain composed, another way to support accessing the properties of the `_Access` class would be to override the `__getattr__` method [[PEP 562](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/#specification)] of `Logs`

> The `__getattr__` function at the module level should accept one
> argument which is the name of an attribute and return the computed
> value or raise an AttributeError:
>
> ```
> def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...
> ```
>
> If an attribute is not found on a module object through the normal
> lookup (i.e. `object.__getattribute__`), then `__getattr__` is
> searched in the module `__dict__` before raising an `AttributeError`.
> If found, it is called with the attribute name and the result is
> returned. Looking up a name as a module global will bypass module
> `__getattr__`. This is intentional, otherwise calling `__getattr__`
> for builtins will significantly harm performance.

E.g.

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Any


class _Access(NamedTuple):
    foo: str
    bar: str


class Logs:
    def __init__(self, log: str) -> None:
        self.log = log
        self.access = _Access(*log.split())

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        return getattr(self.access, name)
```

When you request an attribute of `Logs` which is not present it will try to access the attribute through the `Logs.access` attribute. Meaning you can write code like this:

```
logs = Logs("fizz buzz")
print(f"{logs.log=}, {logs.foo=}, {logs.bar=}")
```

```
logs.log='fizz buzz', logs.foo='fizz', logs.bar='buzz'
```

Note that this would not preserve the typing information through to the `Logs` object in most static analyzers and autocompletes. That to me would be a compelling enough reason not to do this, and continue to use the more verbose way of accessing values as you describe in your question.

If you still really need this, and want to remain type safe. Then I would add properties to the `Logs` class which fetch from the `_Access` object.

```
class Logs:
    def __init__(self, log: str) -> None:
        self.log = log
        self.access = _Access(*log.split())

    @property
    def foo(self) -> str:
        return self.access.foo

    @property
    def bar(self) -> str:
        return self.access.bar
```

This avoids the type safty issues, and depending on how much code you write using the `Logs` instances, still can cut down on other boilerplate dramatically.

Comment: This is an ugly solution because the setattr on `Logs` still "works", and then names in the instance namespace will shadow the `__getattr__` proxying. Gross.

Comment: @wim agreed, there's a lot of downsides. This answers solves the direct question, but I wouldn't want to see that in production code. I'm posting it here for completeness sake.

Comment: What about the `@property` solution?  That should be good, right?  I actually think this might be the best way to handle it.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I think that approach is fine. Depends on how often you need to write this kind of pattern. It's a lot of boilerplate and not particularly DRY, so human error can seep in.